# Why did my code turn into another language..?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Basically, I touched something in visual studio code that made my .js script turn into a SQL script but the script name is main.js and not main.sql

This is how the file looks:

[image]

And this is how the code editor looks:

[image]

Also, there is a file name data with a SQL file in it that file is normal I was just practicing SQL was also trying to see if i can store data with SQL for a discord bot

Comment: by default the shortcut to re-open the language mode is `CTRL-K` (then release), then `M`. It's probably also listed on your status bar, near the bottom right corner (after the encoding & CRLF/LF indicators), but i'm not 100% sure if that is enabled by default.

Comment: just close the file and open it again, then VSC will set the correct languageID based on extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to fix this:

Firstly you can change the language mode by clicking on the bottom where it says the language mode:
[image]

You will then be prompted to change your language mode

You can also do this in the command pallete

Press `ctrl + shift + p` (by default) and the command prompt will pop up, type `change language mode` and the option will then appear.

You can also press `ctrl + m` and then `k` by default, where you have the ability to change the language mode there